# Ошибка в обновлении миграции при работе с MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

Пытаюсь обновить базу данных на сервере, до этого делал пробный вариант без Identity и все работало, но при подключении Identity к базе данных выдает ошибку.
Ошибка:

```
PM> Update-DataBase
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test_db' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test_db' AND TABLE_NAME='__EFMigrationsHistory';
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `MigrationId`, `ProductVersion`
      FROM `__EFMigrationsHistory`
      ORDER BY `MigrationId`;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20230927140423_CreateIdentitySchema'.
Applying migration '20230927140423_CreateIdentitySchema'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (375ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
          `Id` char(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
          `Name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `NormalizedName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
Failed executing DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
    `Id` char(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `NormalizedName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'AspNetRoles' already exists
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 468
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 296
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 107
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Table 'AspNetRoles' already exists
```

Миграция, в которой находится ошибка:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetRoles",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "char(36)", nullable: false, collation: "ascii_general_ci"),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4"),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: true)
            .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4")
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
    })
    .Annotation("MySql:CharSet", "utf8mb4");
```

Код из Program, который отвечает за подключение к БД и работу с Identity

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options
        .UseMySql(
            connectionString, 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 34))
        ));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config =>
{
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    config.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 64;
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.Database.Migrate();
});
```

Comment: Ошибку целиком покажите. Там выводит огромную портянку с подробнейшей информацией о проблеме, из которой вы взяли лишь заголовок "ОШИБКА" и выполняемый SQL.

Comment: С точки зрения MySQL запрос совершенно легитимен. Хотя он и кривой до невозможности - но это от кривого скрипта... Включайте на MySQL вывод в General Log и смотрите точный текст запроса, который пришёл от клиента - только там можно найти причину ошибки. Сам клиент напишет явную ерунду и не признается...

Comment: Ну теперь, по-моему, проблема очевидна: `Table 'AspNetRoles' already exists`.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо большое, я что-то сразу и не понял этой ошибки

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных уже существовала таблица AspNetRoles